# Create a procedure to give bonuses to employees

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, procedure

- I'm a beginner of PL/SQL.
- I need to create a procedure.
- The procedure name is `sp_emp_bonus` that takes 3 parameters:

  - `department_id`
  - `job_id`
  - `amount`
- The procedure will update of bonus of employees within the `department_id` and `job_id` and increase existing bonus by the amount.

After the `update` statement, print using `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE`  to print out the number of employees affected by update (hint use implicit cursor attribute).

If no employees found then an exception section should capture NO_DATA_FOUND and print employees not found.  Also include error handling for `WHEN OTHERS ... and print DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(SUBSTR(SQLERRM,1,100));`

How to write this?

Comment: You shouldn't uses prefix for database object names, and you especially should not use `sp_` as a prefix because it's reserved by Microsoft: https://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix (UPDATE: I see you're using Oracle - so the `sp_` prohibition doesn't apply, but I still think using any kind of object-type name prefix (like Systems Hungarian notation) is bad practice).

Comment: Your post reads like a homework assignment. Please elaborate on the background and nature of your question.

Comment: Where's your code?  What have you tried so far?  What does the data look like?

Comment: You should start with writing the plain update query and the documentation on syntax of `CREATE PROCEDURE`. Then you can post another question with detailed explanation and confusing points you get so far.

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple `update` statement and `sql%rowcount` in procedure as follows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SP_EMP_BONUS (
    P_DEPARTMENT_ID   IN   NUMBER,
    P_JOB_ID          IN   NUMBER,
    P_AMOUNT          IN   NUMBER
) AS
    LV_UPDATED_COUNT NUMBER := 0;
BEGIN
    UPDATE YOUR_TABLE
       SET
        SALARY = SALARY + AMOUNT
     WHERE DEPARTMENT_ID = P_DEPARTMENT_ID
       AND JOB_ID = P_JOB_ID;

    LV_UPDATED_COUNT := SQL%ROWCOUNT;
    IF LV_UPDATED_COUNT = 0 THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('no records found');
    ELSE
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Number of records updated: ' || LV_UPDATED_COUNT);
    END IF;

END SP_EMP_BONUS;
/
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I'll try it!

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will answer your question:

```
create or replace procedure sp_emp_bonus(
    ip_dep_id in departments.department_id%type,
    ip_job_id in jobs.job_id%type,
    amount in number
)
is
    no_emp_found exception;
    pragma exception_init(no_emp_found, -20101);
    cnt integer := 0;
begin
    update
        employees e
            set e.salary = e.salary + nvl(amount, 0)
        where
            e.department_id = ip_dep_id and
            e.job_id = ip_job_id;
    cnt := sql%rowcount;
    if cnt = 0 then
        raise no_emp_found;
    else
        dbms_output.put_line('Employees updated ' || cnt);
    end if;
    commit;
exception
    when no_emp_found then
        rollback;
        dbms_output.put_line('No Employees found for given Department and Job');
    when OTHERS then
        rollback;
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(SUBSTR(SQLERRM,1,100));
end;
```

Thanks.